# Getting specific Column count in crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I would like to get the count of columns that contains a "P" in Column 'P' and count of columns that contains an "A" in Column 'A' for each row respectively in crystal reports.

The imaginary result is displayed as an image below.
[image: Image of Crystal report with imaginary result]

Comment: I haven't found any solutions to my question prior making a new question here.

Comment: You always have 13 columns to check?

Comment: Actually, there are 31 Columns to check, but I screenshot only 13 columns. Column 31 will be  null in cases where a month has only 28/29/30 days.
This is a report generated for calculating attendance of employee in a month. P: Present, A:Absent

Comment: Isn't easier to add 2 new columns in dataSource and check all those attendance in C# than making Crystal Report function which will have to check all that columns 1 by 1?

Comment: Yes, but I'm getting loads of data, say 2000 records in total.
So, C# loop may consume much time than CR.

Before that to get the query result, I am already transforming rows as columns. I mean whatever we see as Day01 Day02 are indeed the data of other column and I have transformed the data like this. And this query nearly takes 19 to 22 seconds [depending on LAN connectivity]

Comment: have you tried cross tabs?

Comment: @Siva , I don't know how to work with them. This is my second report and I'm amateur in CR.

Comment: Create a cross tab and take days in column part and at the end you get totals...

Comment: 2000 records in datasource will be faster processed in C# than in Crystal report. And if you are new to CR then it's smarter to create that 2 columns programaticly than making functions which you won't understand what they do or cross tab. Just an advice

Comment: @KuKeC
Thanks for the advice and information. Will try both and post which is better here.

Thank you again.

Comment: @Siva
Thanks for the information. Will try both and post which is better here.

Thank you again.

Comment: @VSVAdityaSarma, have you done with this issue?

Comment: @DareDevil, Thank you for the concern and sorry that I did not post my status. I have used for loop in C# rather than cross tabs or any other in CR. I'm done with this very recently. Thank you.